# In opengl, Can I use two MatrixMode at the same time?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, opengl-compat

My question is simple. I wonder if I can use GL_MODELVIEW and GL_PROJECTION at the same time or not ?

Comment: In legacy OpenGL each vertex coordinates is transformed by the current model view matrix and then by the current projection matrix. Note, there are even 4 current matrices:  `GL_MODELVIEW`, `GL_PROJECTION`, `GL_TEXTURE` and `GL_COLOR`. See [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml). What do you mean by *"use at the same time"*? You can't "use" them, the matrices are applied to the vertex attributes automatically, except when you use a shader. But if you use a shader, then you should not use the legacy matrices at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both model-view and projection matrices are always active, i.e. the positions of vertices you draw are multiplied by both.

`glMatrixMode` only affects which matrix is modified when you call the matrix-related functions (`glLoadIdentity|Rotate|Translate`, etc). Those always modify one of the two matrices, never both.